# Как узнать размер словаря, вложенного в список?

Tags: c#, list, словари

Есть список словарей, нужно узнать размер именно словаря, как достучаться через список к элементам этого списка?

Объект класса ItemSet у меня по сути представляет собой словарь вида `Dictionary <List <string>, int>`

```
        public List<ItemSet> ItemSetGeneration(int supp, List<ItemSet> prevItemSet)
    {
        ItemSet nextItemSet = new ItemSet();

        if (prevItemSet == null)
        {
            nextItemSet = firstItemSet;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < prevItemSet[0].Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < prevItemSet[1].Count; j++)
                {
                    ItemSet tempItemSet = new ItemSet();                        
                    tempItemSet = UnionOfItemSet(prevItemSet[i], prevItemSet[j]);

                    foreach(var item in tempItemSet)
                    {
                        if (item.Value >= supp) nextItemSet.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ItemSetList.Add(nextItemSet);

        return ItemSetList;
    }
```

Comment: Вот так:  prevItemSet[index] - здесь мы уже обратились к словарю. prevItemSet[0].Count - узнали размер первого словаря. Решение и так же есть.

Comment: мне показалось, что так не работает, потому что ошибка была, что индекс за пределами, а сейчас дошло. спасибо.